# Does Elasticsearch performs full table scan on my Oracle table everytime when Logstash is run?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

I wanted to know if the Elasticsearch performs the full table scan on my Oracle table if I try to ingest that table's delta data using Logstash

Comment: How exactly do you ingest the table's delta data using Logstash?

Comment: using sql_last_value parameter

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't interact with your database, it's Logstash that runs queries on your database. Whether Logstash scans the entire table depends on the query itself and the scanned table indexes. Most queries run from Logstash look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD_FOR_DELTA > :sql_last_value;
```

If `FIELD_FOR_DELTA` doesn't have an index then Oracle will search through all records to find entries satisfying the condition. But when `FIELD_FOR_DELTA` has an index then Oracle will either search through small portion of the table or will only check the record with highest value and finish the query if the value was equal or smaller. If you don't have an index for this field in your table then you should consider it, because of potentially improved query performance and lowered DB impact from Logstash.